# Self Joins and Efficiency vs Subqueries

Tags: sql

Suppose we have a table called  `actions(date, uid, pid, action, description)`   . A  sample of the table is shown below:

```
Table: actions
date         uid        pid         action            description
'2018-10-19' 1234        12           'view'         
'2018-10-19' 1234        12           'report'        'SPAM' 
'2018-10-19' 5678        23           'reaction'      'LOVE'
```

There is a table also called  `reviewers(date, rid, pid)` . Reviewers are people that remove a post. A reviewer is not a user. A sample of the table is shown below:

```
Table: reviewers
 date         rid                    pid
'2018-10-19'  567                    12
'2018-10-19'  890                    45
```

What percent of daily content that users look at (takes any action) is actually Spam?

Would the following work:

**Case 1: "Look at" means any action**

```
select u.date, count(distinct r.pid)/count(distinct uu.pid))*100
from actions u join actions uu
on u.pid = uu.pid
inner join reviewers r
on u.pid = r.pid
where u.description = 'SPAM'
group by 1
```

**Case 2: "Look at" means action = 'view'**

```
 select u.date, count(distinct r.pid)/count(distinct uu.pid))*100
    from actions u join actions uu       
    on u.pid = uu.pid
    inner join reviewers r
    on u.pid = r.pid
    where u.description = 'SPAM'
    and uu.action = 'VIEW'
    group by 1
```

Comment: Not quite understand why you join table [reviewers] if your question is "What percent of daily content that `USERS` look at is actually Spam?" unless your question is "What percent of daily content that `REVIEWERS` look at is actually Spam?"

Comment: @jyao: Because users can report a post and say that it is SPAM, but reviewers actually check to see if it is spam and remove it.

Comment: Ok, @alexxx, that makes sense now.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what the calculation is.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: We want to find the % of posts that viewers look at are actually spam (i.e. they are removed from the reviewers).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I have edited my solution. Do you think my solution makes sense?

Comment: @alexxx . . . What does "look at" mean?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Let's assume for now that its whenever a user takes any action. In another case lets assume that it is when the action is 'view.'

Comment: @GordonLinoff: So is my solution correct???

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you need the reviewers table at all for this? Are you asking for the percentage of pages that get reviewed? if not then it's all in the actions table I think.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `join` twice.  If I understand correctly:

```
select u.date, 
       avg(case when u.description = 'SPAM' then 1.0 else 0 end)
from actions u left join
     reviewers r
     on u.pid = r.pid
group by u.date;
```

Hmmm. . . You need to aggregate before joining.  So this might be better:

```
select u.date, 
       avg(case when u.description = 'SPAM' then 1.0 else 0 end)
from (select date, uid, pid,
             max(case when u.description = 'SPAM' then 1 else 0 end) as is_spam
      from actions u
      group by date, uid, pid
     ) u left join
     reviewers r
     on u.pid = r.pid
group by u.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure why `reviewers` needs to be considered, or if a pid can be repeated in that table, but I think this will do what you need (50.0% from the sample)

```
select 
    count(distinct (case when description = 'SPAM' and r.pid IS NOT NULL then pid end)) * 100.0
     /
    count(distinct pid) 
from actions a
left join (
     select distinct pid from reviewers 
     ) r on r.pid = a.pid
;
```

Comment: Does your metod provide the correct results? Have you tested all your test cases?